# Set document title on client and server side

Tags: reactjs

I want to know how you set the title of each page with ReactJS. And more, I use react-router-component and i want use same tech to set title to each page at server side by using React.renderComponentToString.

My current root Component :

```jsx
module.exports = App = React.createClass
  getInitialState: ->
    return title: 'My title'

  render: ->
    <html lang="fr">
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/main.css" />
        <script src="/assets/js/bundle.js"></script>
        <title>{@state.title}</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="body-content">
          <div id="main-container">
            <Content path={@props.path} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

And my Content component :

```jsx
Content = React.createClass
  render: ->
    <Locations id="main" className="App" path={@props.path}>
      <Location path="/" handler={MainPage} />
      <Location path="/users/:username" handler={UserPage} />
    </Locations>
```

Comment: As far as I see it you are already setting the title. What exactly do you expect to happen? What does not work?

Comment: I wish that React Component can change title on both client and server side. Client side is OK because i can change title just with document.title, but it doesn't work on server side.

Comment: Can you give more of your code? On the server, the component is rendered only once, so I can't imagine where that ›changing‹ could happen.

Comment: For SEO for exemple, every component will render for each page, so I want the component decide the title of the page on server side

Comment: https://gist.github.com/koistya/24715d295fbf710d1e24 - How to set document.title with React and Flux

Answer (score 2):

#### Top-level React component

```js
var React = require('react');
var AppStore = require('../stores/AppStore');

var Application = React.createClass({

  propTypes: {
    path: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    onSetTitle: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
  },

  render() {
    var page = AppStore.getPage(this.props.path);
    this.props.onSetTitle(page.title);
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1>{page.title}</h1>
        <div return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: page.body}}>;
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = Application;
```

#### Client-side startup script (entry point)

```js
var React = require('react');
var Dispatcher = require('./core/Dispatcher');
var Application = require('./components/Application');

Dispatcher.register((payload) => {
  var action = payload.action;
  if (action.actionType === ActionTypes.CHANGE_LOCATION) {
    app.setProps({path: action.path});
  }
});

var app = React.createElement(Application, {
  path: window.location.pathname,
  onSetTitle: (title) => document.title = title
}));
app = React.render(app, document.body);
```

**More info**: https://gist.github.com/koistya/24715d295fbf710d1e24 
**Demo Project**: https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit

Comment: It looks like you don't need to check the execution environment for `componentDidMount` as it seems to only be called client side: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount

Answer (score 1):

to pass the title to your `App` component server side, you have to pass it the same way as you're passing the `path`, i.e. as `props` and not `state`.

So first you'll need to change:

```
<title>{@state.title}</title>
```

To:

```
<title>{@props.title}</title>
```

Then in your backend pass the wanted title to the `App` component when instantiating it, like so:

```
var url = require('url');
var ReactAsync = require('react-async');

var App = require('./path/to/your/root-component.jsx');

// app = your express app:
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
  var title = getTitleFromPath(path); // Made up function to get title from a path..
  ReactAsync.renderComponentToStringWithAsyncState(
    App({path: path, title: title}),
    function (err, markup) {
      if (err) return res.send(500, err);
      res.send('<!DOCTYPE html>\n' + markup);
    }
  );
});
```

Hope that helps!

As for setting the title client side I think your solution with setting the `document.title` probably is the best option.

**Update**

I've now tested the above and the title is set correctly, however React gets a different checksum for the server generated component and the client generated one, which is no good:

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: You're trying to render a component to the document using server rendering but the checksum was invalid
```

So actually **you shouldn't use this solution!**

Will have to play around a little more...